# Method of moments estimator for $\theta^2$ when $X_i\sim p_{\theta}(x)=\frac{2x}{\theta^2}1_{0{\leq}x{\leq}\theta}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be from a sample from a probability distribution:

$$p_{\theta}(x) = \frac{2x}{\theta^2}1_{0{\leq}x{\leq}\theta}$$

, where $\theta > 0$ is an unknown parameter.

I have found from (i) and (ii) of the question that the unbiased method of moments estimator for $\theta$ is $\frac{3\bar{X}}{2}$.

(iii) asks for an estimator for $\theta^2$, which I found to be $2\bar{X^2}$ using the second moment of the distribution. However, this is inconsistent with the answer in my textbook which says that it is $(\frac{3\bar{x}}{2})^2$.
I am confused as to the method my textbook used to arrive at this answer. It seems that the estimator for $\theta$ is simply squared, which I assumed is only possible for Maximum Likelihood Estimators when the function of $\theta$ is bijective.

(iv) asks for an unbiased estimator for $\theta^2$, which if I were to use the estimator as given by my textbook, I would require the variance of the distribution to compute, which I am unable to obtain.

Would really appreciate some help on this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asked for only a method of moments estimator of $\theta^2$ ?

Comment: The exact phrasing of the question is simply: Give the method of moments estimator for $\theta^2$

Comment: If you are using sample raw moments to equate with population raw moments, then shouldn't you have $\frac{\theta^2}{2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k^2\implies \hat\theta^2(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=\frac{2}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k^2$ ? Your book's answer is different though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method of moments estimator for $\theta^{2}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930323/method-of-moments-estimator-for-theta2)